# Why did I get a serial voting reversal for a vote on a single post?

Tags: support, reputation, voting, serial-voting

From the [help center](https://askubuntu.com/help/serial-voting-reversed), "serial voting" means:

> When a single user continually votes (up or down) on many of your posts within a short period of time, the system considers these votes
> to be invalid and removes them. This could happen for a variety of
> reasons, such as a user finding a user's great answer and visiting all
> of their posts to upvote them, or a user getting into an argument with
> another user and downvoting their posts indiscriminately in revenge.
> No matter the cause, this sort of systematic targeted voting is not
> considered normal behavior and the system will not allow it.

My understanding of the above description is that serial voting is defined as votes from a user for many posts that were created by a single user, so serial voting should always consist of *more than 1 vote*. Am I right? I looked through posts on meta about serial voting and found that every case concerned more than 2 votes.

But why did I get a serial voting reversal for a vote on a *single* post?

[image: Serial voting image]

On [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/tour), I only had three posts that were voted on. And I think all voters are unique users, so there should not have been any serial voting.

Comment: It would probably be more applicable if you had more posts but if you post once a month and I downvote or upvote you everytime you post then that's a "serial vote", if there was enough time between each post then every vote may not be reserved (only those within a certain interval, just the last one). --- The exact algorithm changes over the years and exactly what and when isn't updated. --- It's an attempt to categorize ill intent in an algorithm, without causing further wrong (or too much). --- So a single or double reversal isn't impossible, and I've seen triple serial that wasn't reversed.

Comment: The exact details are likely to remain not in the public domain to avoid people finding loopholes to abuse - that's what we've been told several times and it makes sense.