# The "learn more" explanation for Voting Correction does not cover all scenarios

Tags: feature-request, status-review, help-center, serial-voting

The wording of the [learn more](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/serial-voting-reversed) for *Voting corrected* refers specifically and exclusively to multiple votes:

> When a single user continually **votes (up or down) on many of your posts** within a short period of time, the system considers **these votes** to be invalid and removes **them.** This could happen for a variety of reasons, such as a user finding a user's great answer and visiting all of their posts to upvote them, or a user getting into an argument with another user and downvoting their posts indiscriminately in revenge. No matter the cause, this sort of **systematic targeted voting** is not considered normal behavior and the system will not allow it.

However on 19/10/21 I had just **one** upvote corrected, which does not fit this explanation or the definition of serial voting (abuse).

- Should the wording be amended to reflect that corrections can be as a result of singular as well as multiple votes?

Related (and a possible duplicate?):  [Non-serial voting corrected](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/362020/non-serial-voting-corrected) which is tagged "status-by-design", and the accepted answer concludes with:

> If we choose to continue using this process to invalidate mass voting sprees like this, we will find a way to clarify this possible case in the help center.

Comment: Agree, yesterday I also asked about it because I was confused by an incomplete explanation: [Why did I get a serial voting reversal for a vote on a single post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371020/why-did-i-get-a-serial-voting-reversal-for-a-vote-on-a-single-post)