# Is "Voting corrected" used for other purposes?

Tags: discussion, voting, serial-voting

I just had 22 upvotes "corrected" by "the system" for which is linked help says (emphasis mine):

> When a single user continually votes (up or down) on many of your posts **within a short period of time**, the system considers these votes to be invalid and removes them.

Looking back over my reputation history, there is no burst of any upvotes "within a short period of time".

Is this category of correction sometimes used as a general category for special voting adjustments?

Comment: There has been a very large manual voting correction on Stack Overflow - see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/412963/2670892)

Comment: Yep, this is apparently related to the same voting ring actions reversal. as the one 
Tim Biegeleisen reported on MSE. The voting correction timestamp for you and Tim matches - it's 2021-11-09 20:55:42Z

Comment: I'm a voting mule? Yikes! (don't know why the downvotes btw)

Comment: @Bohemian apparently you weren't the only one. Reportedly this voting ring was spread quite wide by the time it was caught. In fact, I feel left out - I've not been affected by this voting correction. I think the fraudulent voters haven't been very welcoming by excluding me. And that's just not nice.

Comment: @VLAZ 20k rep is too low to be worth their time. :-P

Comment: @Bohemian downvotes are likely because you doubt the mechanism, and moreover, turns out this specific case isn't automatic but rather result of hard labor of actual people who tracked down massive voting rings.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Non-serial voting corrected](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/362059/282094) and  https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126857/282094 - as accurate as humans carefully studying the problem and making a *cutting line decision* - there can be a bit of inaccuracy, a loss, but a line must be drawn somewhere; one that balances the most fairness to the most people.

Comment: "*Based on my history, it seems unlikely that I have accumulated 22 questionable upvotes.*" It's frankly *impossible* to say this with any confidence when you have received some ~*37,000* upvotes over nearly 12 years. Unless you are thinking only serial upvotes within seconds of each other count as potentially fraudulent (which isn't accurate).

Comment: @TylerH it was the phrase *within a short period of time* in the linked help page that threw me. The help page probably needs amending.

Comment: there are scripts on the SE network that run every X amount of time; that are in charge of validating the concurrence of votes of the users; if your votes are consecutive; and there is no prudent time between each one, the system will determine that they are false votes ... and it will automatically reverse them; This works very well for negative votes, especially when one user is cruel to another.

Comment: As an aside, I don't know why this question is being hammered by downvotes. I seems more or less a reasonable question to me. If the community think it's "bad" I would rather delete it, but of course I can't `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: @Delete voter, I think this post is an excellent signpost to keep, as it uses a vastly different title, and different verbiage then the duplicate. No need to go and delete everything that is a duplicate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This specific case isn't ordinary voting correction, it's the result of manual voting ring detection and removing all the false votes cast by those involved.

You are not part of the voting ring itself of course, but rather one of many who got affected. The votes being reversed should have never been  cast in the first place, so their removal is justified and correct, and the loss of rep is inevitable side effect of this.

For more details, read the question and answers on Meta Stack Overflow, describing a previous case: [Tag badge scores gained from votes are lost without change in reputation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408724/tag-badge-scores-gained-from-votes-are-lost-without-change-in-reputation)

Comment: I see. All cool. Maybe the linked help page could be enhanced with something like “Sometimes this is a result of corrective measures taken due to other users engaging in broader voting fraud activity, rather than them targeting you specifically” or some such.

Comment: @Bohemian if such cases will keep happening then yeah, this better be added to the Help Center somehow, agree.

Comment: Related: [The "learn more" explanation for Voting Correction does not cover all scenarios](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371056/the-learn-more-explanation-for-voting-correction-does-not-cover-all-scenarios)

Comment: it was the phrase *within a short period of time* in the help page that threw me. It wouldn’t hurt to embellish the help page with a catch-all for special circumstances like this..